# Web-scraping with rvest works with first page of website, but not others

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

Here is the code I'm using to get the link to the next page of the website.

```
url <- 'https://uws-community.symplicity.com/index.php?s=student_group'
webpage <- read_html(url)
next_link <- html_nodes(webpage,".paging_nav a") %>% html_attr('href')
```

Then, using that link, I'm trying to get the next page after that.

```
url2 <- paste0("https://uws-community.symplicity.com/index.php", 
next_link)

webpage2 <- read_html(url2)
next_link2 <- html_nodes(webpage2,".paging_nav a") %>% html_attr('href')
```

This second part gives me "Character (empty)" for next_link2. Why is this? Why did the same method work on the first page but not on the second page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site set up some cookies and you need to reuse them on the next scrape.

```
library(rvest)

url <- 'https://uws-community.symplicity.com/index.php?s=student_group'
page <- html_session(url)

page2 <- page %>% follow_link(css = ".paging_nav a:last-child")
page3 <- page2 %>% follow_link(css = ".paging_nav a:last-child")

page3 %>% html_nodes(".grpl-grp")
```

This will return the table from third page.